# How to shift an array elements by n places in C

Tags: c, arrays

If we have an array, for example, Arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5} and I want to shift the elements by 2, how can I do that?
the the array should be: {3,4,5,1,2}.
I tried to slove this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int broj,pom,i,niza1[10],niza2[10],raz,tem=0,rest=0;

  scanf("%d%d",&broj,&pom);//broj= number of elements and pom=shifting
  for (int i=0;i<broj;i++){
    scanf ("%d",&niza1[i]);
  }
  raz=broj-pom;//difrence between thenumber of elements and shifting
    for (int i=raz;i<=broj;i++){
      niza2[tem]=niza1[i-1];
      tem++;

    }
       for (int i=0;i<broj;i++){
      printf("%d",niza2[i]);
      }

    return 0;
}
```

input: 5 2 
       1 2 3 4 5
resault: 3 4 5 0 0

How can I add the last two numbers inside the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only copying `broz - raz` elements into new array.

```
  raz=broj-pom;//difrence between thenumber of elements and shifting
    for (int i=raz;i<=broj;i++){
      niza2[tem]=niza1[i-1];
      tem++;

    }
```

should be

1. I removed unnecessary `tem` variable.
2. `(i+raz)%broj` you need `%` to wrap the copying.

   ```
   raz=broj-pom;//difrence between thenumber of elements and shifting
   for (int i=0;i<broj;i++){
     niza2[i]=niza1[(i+raz)%broj];
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working! The code is simple and easy to learn/work with.